# How to reload page by react-router-dom after change language (react-i18next)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom, react-i18next

I have some problem with react.

I need reload page and refetch data after change language  without `window.location`.

I use react, redux, react-router-dom, react-i18next and more

I don't want to use `componentWillReceiveProps` and check
if my params `en` has changed to (`uk` or `ru`) and then call method for trigger redux action and make some request.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: why not keep the language data in the top level of the app and use `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: Presumably the act of changing the language will trigger some sort of redux action. That redux action can be handled by swapping out all relevant resources in one language with resources in another language. You can either pre-load all language data and swap them out when you need them or just load the data as part of the action reducer (maybe [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) can help with this, don't know, never used it)

Comment: @EricHasselbring , thanks for the answer, this is a good solution, but the problem with redux dispatch. Нow to let redux understand fetch data? When I have route /hotels I need method  fetch hotels data. When /skipasses  - fetch skipasses data . If I will use componentDidUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps  in top level I will not know what method should I call.

Comment: @apokryfos , thanks for answer) I don't want to pull all the language as one, I keep it inside i18next.init as resources

Comment: this still works, you can use componentDidUpdate in all the main pages and have them refetch data on language change.  I can't think of or see there being a simple abstraction that can allow behavior to auto fire new ajax requests with out some complex logic or a new design pattern like all page components having an `init` function and then calling that

Comment: I have 30 pages where I'm doing a fetch data) I'll have to write in each one componentDidUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps.I thought there is an easy way to do this